# calculatorfinal.CalculatorFinal class wasn't found in calculatorFinal project

Tags: java

I am new to java and unsure why I keep getting this error message. When I right click and run the file it runs fine. However when I hit the run button it gives me that error message. Also is there a way to save the data that the user enters?

```
package calculatorfinal;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CalculatorFinal extends Applet{

TextArea screen;

Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero,
    div, mult, sub, ad, eq, clear;

int total, num, lastnum;
String st, st1;
char oper;
boolean operon=false;


public CalculatorFinal(){}

public String getAppletInfo()
{
    return "Name: Calculator Final" +
           "Author: Mike Braddy";
}

public void init()
{
    resize(100, 150);
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    screen=new TextArea("",1,12);
    add(screen);

    one=new Button("1");
    two=new Button("2");
    three=new Button("3");
    four=new Button("4");
    five=new Button("5");
    six=new Button("6");
    seven=new Button("7");
    eight=new Button("8");
    nine=new Button("9");
    zero=new Button("0");

    div=new Button("/");
    mult=new Button("*");
    sub=new Button("-");
    ad=new Button("+");
    eq=new Button("=");
    clear=new Button("c");

    add(seven);
    add(eight);
    add(nine);
    add(div);
    add(four);
    add(five);
    add(six);
    add(mult);
    add(one);
    add(two);
    add(three);
    add(sub);
    add(clear);
    add(zero);
    add(eq);
    add(ad);
}

public void destroy(){}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){}

public void start(){}

public void stop(){}

public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg)
{
    if(evt.target instanceof Button)
    {
        if(evt.target==one)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("1");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("1");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==two)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("2");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("2");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==three)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("3");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("3");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==four)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("4");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("4");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==five)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("5");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("5");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==six)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("6");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("6");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==seven)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("7");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("7");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==eight)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("8");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("8");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==nine)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("9");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("9");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==zero)
        {
            if(operon==false)
            {
                screen.appendText("0");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                screen.setText("0");
                operon=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(evt.target==div)
        {
            oper='/';
            st=screen.getText();
            lastnum=Integer.parseInt(st);
            operon=true;
        }
        else if(evt.target==mult)
        {
            oper='*';
            st=screen.getText();
            lastnum=Integer.parseInt(st);
            operon=true;
        }
        else if(evt.target==sub)
        {
            oper='-';
            st=screen.getText();
            lastnum=Integer.parseInt(st);
            operon=true;
        }
        else if(evt.target==ad)
        {
            oper='+';
            st=screen.getText();
            lastnum=Integer.parseInt(st);
            operon=true;
        }
        else if(evt.target==clear)

        {
            screen.setText("");
            total=0;
        }
        else //eq
        {
            if(oper == '/')
            {
                st=screen.getText();
                num=Integer.parseInt(st);
                total=lastnum/num;
            }
            else if(oper == '*')
            {
                st=screen.getText();
                num=Integer.parseInt(st);
                total=lastnum*num;
            }
            else if(oper == '-')
            {
                st=screen.getText();
                num=Integer.parseInt(st);
                total=lastnum-num;
            }
            else if(oper == '+')
            {
                st=screen.getText();
                num=Integer.parseInt(st);
                total=lastnum+num;
            }
            st1=Integer.toString(total);
            screen.setText(st1);
            lastnum=0;
            oper='!';
            operon=true;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you've posted far more code than is relevant to your question, and that you've asked two distinct questions. Please read how to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your IDE. If you're using Eclipse, the green run button in the menu bar runs the most recently run project. You can hit the drop-down arrow to see which project it is running. The easiest way to ensure you're running the project you want is by right clicking on the project and clicking run, like you've been doing. If your cursor is inside of a class file from a project, the run button should run that project.

As far as saving data from the user, you kind of already do that using the TextArea, although the input is in the form of numbers that get appended through buttons. If you want to save the text in the TextArea elsewhere, you could store it in a String. If you wanted data to be persistent between runs (to last after the program), you could store it in a text file. I like to use FileWriter to do that. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm)'s a tutorial for that.

Comment: I am using netbeans

Comment: In netbeans you have to compile the program first (that converts it from java code to commands the computer can understand). Right click on the coffee symbol of your program and press build. Then you should be able to run the program with the run button.